# error filtering data: Faceting variables must have at least one value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bioinformatics, facet-wrap

I am trying to write a code by using dplyr and a yeast dataset

I Read in the data with this code

```
gdat <- read_csv(file = "brauer2007_tidy1.csv")
```

I ommitted na's by using this

```
gdat <- na.omit(gdat)


library(ggplot2)
```

Then I tried to filter some genes according to their column name "symbol" and used ggplot to make a plot

```
filter(gdat, symbol=="QRI7", symbol== "CFT2", symbol== "RIB2",
             symbol=="EDC3", symbol=="VPS5", symbol=="AMN1" & rate=.05) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=rate,
           y=expression, 
           group=1, 
           colour=nutrient)) + 
geom_line(lwd=1.5) + 
facet_wrap(~nutrient)
```

facet_wrap(~nutrient) is used to seperate each gene's rate vs. expression graphs according to the nutrient which is depleted but this error keeps coming:

> error: Faceting variables must have at least one value

I checked these genes by using the filter function if all of them could be displayed on r and they did when I filtered them individually but when I combine multiple genes with ggplot I get this error.
Also when I use "&rate=.05" I can't get only the values which are at rate=.05.
Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? I have a deadline till tomorrow 17.30 and if somebody could help me I would be very glad, thanks.

Comment: Your filter looks wrong. Commas evaluate to "and" so symbol cannot be, for example, both QRI7 and CFT2. Perhaps you want something like: filter(gdat, symbol %in% c("QRI7", "CFT2", "RIB2", "EDC3", "VPS5", "AMN1"), rate == .05). It's difficult to help further without seeing some of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded what I assume is the same dataset like this:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

gdat <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bioconnector/workshops/master/data/brauer2007_tidy.csv")
```

So the first problem is your `filter`. If you are looking for any of those gene symbols, you need to use `%in%`. And `rate` requires a double equals `==`:

```
gdat %>% 
  filter(symbol %in% c("QRI7", "CFT2", "RIB2", "EDC3", "VPS5", "AMN1"),
         rate == 0.05)
```

I don't think you want to filter for one rate and then use `geom_line`, because you will just get one vertical line at one value of x (rate).

Neither do I think you want to use `geom_line` for multiple values of `rate`, because there are several values for `expression` at each rate and a line will generate a nasty-looking zigzag.

And as you are faceting on nutrient, there's no need to color by nutrient. Perhaps you want to color by gene?

So you need to think about what makes a good visualisation of this data. Here's a simple example to get you started.

```
gdat %>% 
  filter(symbol %in% c("QRI7", "CFT2", "RIB2", "EDC3", "VPS5", "AMN1")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=rate,
             y=expression,
             color = symbol)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~nutrient)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this worked thanks a lot :) also do you know how I can filter all of the genes instead of specific ones in order to categorize them according to the nutrients? I tried using 'gdat%>% filter(rate==0.05)%>% ggplot(aes(x=rate,y=expression, group=1, colour=nutrient))+geom_line(lwd=1.5) + facet_wrap(~nutrient)' but this only gives a single line and I want a more zig-zaggy line.

Comment: Glad it helped - please accept the answer if it solved the issue. If "filter all the genes" means plot a line for every gene - I don't think you want to do that. It will be a mess. If that's not what you mean, please clarify.